# Thumb comes out crooked when I use subdivision

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I was leaning to make a hand, but when I apply the subdivision modifier I noticed on the other side of the hand it came out like this with the lower part of the thumb just pointing out.
[image]
[image]

I already try a few ways to try to smooth it out but it does not seem to work if anyone can give me advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, maybe you have flipped normals (select all and press Shift N) or inner faces or unconnected vertices (select all and press M > Merge by Distance)

Comment: In addition to normals, check if you don't have a face inside the hand, or double geometry (for that: select all with A, then M > Merge By Distance).

Comment: Thank you I did not even know about those commands fixed right away thank you very much.